# How do I fix an inconsistent accessibility field type error message while trying to create an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, compiler-errors

I am trying to create interface and I get an error of `inconsistent accessibility field type`.

I don't know what that means or how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DuckSim
{
    class Program
    {
        //Interfaz de comportamiento de vuelo
        interface flybehavior
        {
            void fly();
        }

        //Clase para los patos que pueden volar que implementa la interdaz de comportamiento de vuelo
        public class flywithwings : flybehavior
        {
            void fly()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I can fly");
            }
        }

        //Clase para los patos que no pueden volar que implementa la interdaz de comportamiento de vuelo
        public class flynoway : flybehavior
        {
            void fly()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I can't fly");
            }
        }

        //Interfaz de comportamiento de grasnido
        interface quackbehavior
        {
            void quack();
        }

        //Clase para los patos que realizan grasnido que implementa la interdaz de comportamiento de grasnido
        public class Quack : quackbehavior
        {
            void quack()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Quack Quack");
            }
        }

        //Clase para los patos que realizan squeak que implementa la interdaz de comportamiento de grasnido
        public class Squeak : quackbehavior
        {
            void quack()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Squeak Squeak");
            }
        }

        //Clase para los patos que no realizan sonido que implementa la interdaz de comportamiento de grasnido
        public class MuteQuack : quackbehavior
        {
            void quack()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I can't quack");
            }
        }





        //Clase principal Patos
        public class Ducks
        {
            quackbehavior qb;
            public void performQuak()
            {
                qb.quack();
            }

            flybehavior fb;
            public void performFly()
            {
                fb.fly();
            }

            public abstract void display();

            public void swim()
            { Console.WriteLine("All ducks can float, even decoys."); }
        }

        //Clase heredada MallarDuck:Duck
        public class MallardDuck : Ducks
        {
            public MallardDuck()
            {
                fb = new flywithwings();
                qb = new Quack();
            }

            public void display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm a real duck");
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ducks mallar = new MallardDuck();
            mallar.performQuak();
            mallar.performFly();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the time to actually read the error message.  It's not particularly cryptic at all.  It explains the exact problem that you have quite clearly.

Comment: You have a good teacher if he gives you Head First Design Patterns to study

Comment: Please use proper naming conventions. This includes proper casing.

Comment: You have a whole bunch of errors there. To start, when you implement an interface, your implementations should be marked as public. Otherwise it isn't implementing the interface! So `fly()` needs to be marked as `public`

Comment: Also you interface needs to be marked as `public`, as does `Main`. Also your `Ducks` class should be abstract and `MallardDuck` needs to `override` `display`. Here's what you need after changing the naming conventions to something more sane: http://dotnetfiddle.net/kzSmZQ

Comment: Thank's all of you for the help, i fix the code, i think that al the interface where public by default that's why i don't explicitly made them public and well the other error's show's i need a lot to learn yet. thank's all of you for the comments